# Sitecore Habitat Demo Repsitory

Tags: unicorn, habitat

I have cloned Sitecore Demo repository from [github](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.git). I have also cloned Sitecore Habitat repository with TDS from [here](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat.git). I have followed the steps mentioned for habitat and able to deploy solution locally using TDS. (Not using Gulp). I have setup this as different repository. i.e (Sitecore Habitat and Sitecore habitat Demo, however deploying on Single Sitecore instance).

I'm Facing below issues

1. As per habitat demo guidelines, I have installed all required modules in Sitecore instance. When I build solution, it is failing due to Sitecore.PrintStudio dlls are missing in reference. Even after doing restore nuget packages I am still unable to build.

Am I missing Anything?

2. I didn't find nuget packages for Unicorn. After manually added nuget packages for Unicorn, Gulp default task is throwing exception as below.

`05-Sync-Unicorn'...
Reading shared secret from C:\websites\Habitat.dev.local\Website/App_config/Include/Unicorn/Unicorn.UI.config
[09:59:12] '05-Sync-Unicorn' errored after 25 ms
[09:59:12] TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at D:\Habitat.Demo\scripts\unicorn.js:26:98
    at Parser.<anonymous> (D:\Habitat.Demo\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:489:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Object.onclosetag (D:\Habitat.Demo\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:447:26)
    at emit (D:\Habitat.Demo\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:640:35)
    at emitNode (D:\Habitat.Demo\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:645:5)
    at closeTag (D:\Habitat.Demo\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:905:7)
    at Object.write (D:\Habitat.Demo\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1452:13)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (D:\Habitat.Demo\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:508:31)`

Authentication provider section in /App_config/Include/Unicorn/Unicorn.UI.config

```
<authenticationProvider type="Unicorn.ControlPanel.Security.ChapAuthenticationProvider, Unicorn">
            <!--<SharedSecret></SharedSecret> Uncomment this line and provide a strong randomized shared secret here. At least 64 characters is recommended, for example https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm -->
            <!-- Authentication challenges are stored in a Sitecore database. You can select which database here. No item installs/templates are required. -->
            <ChallengeDatabase>web</ChallengeDatabase>
            <!-- 
                Writes the reason why failed automated tool authentications failed to the Sitecore logs.
                Will result in writing your shared secret to the logs as part of the signature base,
                so you can disable it if you wish.
            -->
            <WriteAuthFailuresToLog>false</WriteAuthFailuresToLog>
        </authenticationProvider>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found what's causing issue, I have fetched one repository Sitecore Habitat from Hedgehog using "TDS" items. So obviously my Unicorn Serialization setup is missing completely.

Sitecore.Demo repository is not been setup by Hedgehog using TDS items. So I had to setup my repository using Nuget Unicorn packages.

**Regarding Unicorn Script error**

This is fixed by adding shared secret tag in App_config/Unicorn/Unicorn.UI.config